# How do you use a tkinter button to restart the python program?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am currently working on a pong game, but I want to add a reset button in the top left corner of the game, using tkinter. I am very new at this, so please try to explain using plain language. I had tried adding a button, but couldn't figure out how to make it reset the program. Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random
    import time
    import pygame

    class Ball:

        def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.paddle = paddle
            self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
            starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
            random.shuffle(starts)
            self.x = starts[0]
            self.y = -3
            self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
            self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
            self.hit_bottom = False

        def hit_paddle(self, pos):
            paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
                if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                    return True
            return False

        def draw(self):
            self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 3
            if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
                self.hit_bottom = True
            if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
                self.y = -3
            if pos[0] <= 0:
                self.x = 3
            if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
                self.x = -3
    class Paddle:
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 450, 750)
            self.x = 0
            self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

        def draw(self):
            self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[0] <= 0:
                self.x = 0
            elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
                self.x = 0

        def turn_left(self, evt):
            self.x = -3

        def turn_right(self, evt):
            self.x = 3

    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0, 0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=800, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()

    tk.update()

    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

    while 1:
        if ball.hit_bottom == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle.draw()
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would just be to run the program again using code.

Add this line to the place where the button's events are: `exec(open("./your_file.py").read())`.

In essence, the program is literally telling itself to run itself.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, check out `Adi219's` answer, however, I would prefer to rearrange the code as shown below and simply recreate paddle and ball instances.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import pygame

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 450, 750)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3

def restart ():
    global paddle, ball
    canvas.delete (ALL)
    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

def main ():
    global paddle, ball
    tk.update()

    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

    while 1:
        if ball.hit_bottom == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle.draw()
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Pong Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=800, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid (row = 0)
Button (tk, text = "Restart", command = restart).grid (row = 1)

main ()
```